# WinError 3 The system cannot find the path specified, even though the path is valid

Tags: python

I've tested exact same code and now I'm doing it in another folder and I get this annoying problem. I want to note, that the paths I get from prints are valid. 100% valid. The problem is on the os.rename line.
Here's my simple code:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import unquote

directory = 'images'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    url = unquote(filename)
    print('Filename: ' + filename)
    print('Decoded: ' + url)
    print('Source: ' + os.path.join(directory, filename))
    print('Destination: ' + os.path.join(directory, url))
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory, filename), os.path.join(directory, url))
    continue
    
print('Done')
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete output you're getting, including the error messages and stack trace, to the question.  A listing of the `images` directory would be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the path of the file was too long and over the windows limit !

I fixed it by setting LongPathsEnabled in registry from 0 to 1, restarted and it helped !